# AngularJS: nested ng-repeat (array in object) only works if there is one item in array, not when multiple

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay, I have a weird issue. I have an array of objects. Each object contains another array (of strings). I loop over the array of objects using `ng-repeat`. Within the repeated code I `ng-repeat` over the array of strings. For some reason, this nested `ng-repeat` only works when the array of strings contains but one (1) item. When there are more items, it simply doesn't work.

**Code**

Result of `<pre>{{ answer.value | json }}</pre>`

```
[
  "Apothekerskast",
  "Apothekerskast",
  "Koelkast ombouw"
]
```

The `view` (in a gist because posting here causes issues with markdown): https://gist.github.com/fabdrol/898e4ac9760fc358ce81

The data (in JSON), for easy reading: https://gist.github.com/fabdrol/089467fa09dad6e89e81

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [doesn't like duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes), use `track by $index`:

`ng-repeat="val in vals track by $index"`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nedq13q2/