# Is it possible to print regular html tags with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know, if it's possible to print some html tags (text with anchors) from `$scope` variable to output view? Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5672cp2/), I'm trying to print anchors from my database, but they are sometimes hidden in text. Thank you very much! :)

**html:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Html test</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <p data-ng-repeat="line in anchors">
      {{line}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.anchors = [
    "<a href='#'>Something</a>", 
    "Angular ignores html tags :("
  ];
}
```

Comment: Don't use `<a href="#">`. we're not using HTML3.2 anymore, the `#` has had a very clear meaning since 1998: it's a uri fragment identifier for the top of  the document, and will scroll your page if you use it for a link element. If you don't need a navigating link, but you need "to click and trigger javascript", we have `<button>` for that.

Comment: Look at this
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755062/ng-repeat-add-items-angularjs-1-2-26)

Comment: I'll fill the href attribute with a value, this is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possbly with [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive

```js
angular.module('app',['ngSanitize'])
.controller('TodoCtrl',
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.anchors = ["<a href='#'>Something</a>", "Angular not ignores html tags :)"];
});
```

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <h2>Html test</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <p data-ng-repeat="line in anchors" ng-bind-html="line">
      
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mark the HTML as trusted you can inject it into the DOM with ng-bind-html.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($sce){
    return {
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.trustedHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<h1>This is html</h1><h2>Subtitle</h2>');
        }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" my-directive>
    <div data-ng-bind-html="trustedHTML"></div>
</div>
```